# Does Xamarin.iOS has apis to implement newly added iOS 13 Enterprise Single Sign On?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Here are the release notes for Xamarin ios 13 release notes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios13/

I don't see anything related to Enterprise Single Sign-On using SSO Extensions. Any plan to implement this near future?

I hope someone from the Xamarin.iOS team shed some light on this.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Xamarin.iOS team directly?

Comment: I tried to post on xamarin forums, I just signed up, site not allowing me to post there. Is there another way to contact them?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer service question about strategic roadmaps, which is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: there is no such API on the app level, only a system wide extension.

Apples Enterprise SSO Extension is an MDM configured extension (just like any other extension but different type) that *transparently* hooks in some custom SSO solution into the operating system so that apps don’t have to know or deal with SSO.

With that in mind, the question if Xamarin (and I assume you mean iOS apps build with Xamarin) supports Apples Enterprise SSO is YES - just like any other app on such a device that tries to send network requests to a whitelisted host name from an app with a whitelisted bundle id. No extra work to do on the app level since all the magic happens on the iOS level.

If you want to implement such an extension then all you need to do is build an ordinary extensions and define the usual plist, capabilities and project settings to match an Enterprise SSO extension. There are only a few callbacks to implement. The tricky part is the correct MDM configuration.

I’ve successfully got such an extension configured and deployed and it just works.